# Set the limits for the y-axis on rCharts

Tags: r, rcharts

How can I set the limits for a "multiBarChart" plot produced by "rCharts". For example I want that the values of the y-axis are between 1 and 10.

```
data<-data.frame(Var=c(1,2,3,4),
                 Fac1=rep(c("A","B"),2),
                 Fac2=rep(c("Blue","Red"),each=2))

require(rCharts)    

n1 <- nPlot(Var~Fac2, group = "Fac1", data = data, type = "multiBarChart")
n1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at following - exploiting NV3D Y domain with `forceY`:

https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/361

> You can use the chart method and the forceY argument to set the y-axis limits. rCharts tries to stay as close as possible to the API of the original javascript library so that it can take advantage of the full feature set, while still keeping the code base lean.
>
> Here is a minimal example.

```
library(rCharts)
hair_eye = as.data.frame(HairEyeColor)
p2 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = 'Eye', data = subset(hair_eye, Sex == "Female"), type = 'multiBarChart')
p2$chart(color = c('brown', 'blue', '#594c26', 'green'))
p2$chart(forceY = c(0, 100))
p2
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks!